# Elastic Beanstalk fails on environment variables update

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed my Spring boot application to an ELB with `Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.1` platform.

When I am trying to add a new Environment Variable from the AWS Console ( `Configuration` -> `Software`) and I hit `Apply` the update fails and rollbacks to the previous configuration.

This what I get from the AWS Console on my environment dashboard
[image]

Here are some of the logs that might be useful
[image]

The interesting part is when I create a fresh new environment and upload my `.jar` file and add the environment variables at the instantiation of my environment it works (meaning the environment variables are set correctly). The problem occurs when I try to update my environment variables when then environment already exists. Am I missing something?

I tried to use `$ eb setenv` after the `$ eb deploy` from my circleci but I still get the same error.

Comment: Tested this on my playground EB - failure as well. Interesting.

Comment: Been having the same issues since yesterday. Not able to add a new env variable. same errors!

Comment: Interested to hear if you ever found a way around this?
@Marcin answer properly explains the issue, but I've found no solution yet

Answer (score 6):

I've been digging into this. And now I know why it fails.

The reason is that when you add the env variable to your EB, the EB engine is going to **download last application version**, unzip and **replaces** it as current application.

This means, `no deployment hooks` nor `.ebextenstions` scripts are **not executed**. Therefore, if you do any application setup during deployment it is not going to be re-applied, leading to failure.

This is based on my own observations using `Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3` and `single-instance` EB type.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround. If you set your deployment to immutable, this will go away as it’s gonna create a band new ec2 instance for you. Not the best solution if you have quota limitation but it works.